# Numerical Mathematics, Ch.2 problem 5

Tags: numerical-methods

Let $\hat{x}\neq 0$ be an approximation of a non null quantity $x$. Find the relation between the relative error $\epsilon = |x - \hat{x}|/|x|$ and $\tilde{E} = |x - \hat{x}|/|\hat{x}|$

I believe we need to study the conditioning number of both equations and compare them, but I am not exactly sure. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It holds that

$$\hat{E}= \epsilon \cdot \frac{|x|}{|\hat{x}|}$$

Do you see why?

Comment: I think so, is it because in the way you set $\hat{E}$ to be and the way $\epsilon$ is defined? Not sure how to word this

Comment: Yes, you want to write $\hat{E}=\frac{|x-\hat{x}|}{|\hat{x}|}$ in respect to $\epsilon=\frac{|x-\hat{x}|}{|x|}$.
$$$$
So you want to find a $\lambda$ such that $\frac{|x-\hat{x}|}{|\hat{x}|}= \lambda \cdot \frac{|x-\hat{x}|}{|x|} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{|\hat{x}|}= \lambda \cdot \frac{1}{|x|} \Rightarrow \lambda=\frac{|x|}{|\hat{x}|}$

Comment: great, thanks. Did you ever study the book called Numerical Mathematics by Quarteroni, Alfio, Sacco, Riccardo, Saleri, Fausto?

Comment: @MorganWeiss No, I studied Numerical Analysis from an other book.

Comment: which book? I do not have access to solutions for this one which makes solving these problems difficult.

Comment: @MorganWeiss A greek version of this book: G. D. Akrivis, V. A. Dougalis: Introduction to Numerical Analysis.  I don't know if there is a corresponding english version.